# Allow any segment after page url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hi i am having this issue for 2 days of searching and nothing helping .. I've created a page with this url `http://localhost/groac/api` i need to allow having any value after the slug `api` like for example `http://localhost/groac/api/login` or `http://localhost/groac/api/users` etc...

The only thing i found was [custom permalinks](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/)
plugin but it allows me to add a fixed value after page url i need it to be variable please help !

Comment: what is your original wp `site URL` and `blogURL`?

Comment: It is on my localhost [http://localhost/groac/](http://localhost/groac/)  let's assume that it will be [http://www.groac.com](http://www.groac.com)